Issue when building a brand new NextJS app
While setting up a new NextJS web application using this command:
 % npx create-next-app@latest

After answering the usual questions, I end up by getting the following output:
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not    use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a   key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/me/.npm/_cacache/tmp/77a0df01
npm ERR! dest /Users/me/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/db/24/    e07964d6ccc5a41eee89a7d34a81e3c36981db9ed8b0bd8bae24b6db37dbe5ec30bd0ef5ca381d810b7659f760f772    f57f69f947d28b037f0a477a9439df
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/me/.npm/_cacache/tmp/77a0df01' -> '/Users/   me/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/db/24/   e07964d6ccc5a41eee89a7d34a81e3c36981db9ed8b0bd8bae24b6db37dbe5ec30bd0ef5ca381d810b7659f760f772   f57f69f947d28b037f0a477a9439df'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/me/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/db/24/    e07964d6ccc5a41eee89a7d34a81e3c36981db9ed8b0bd8bae24b6db37dbe5ec30bd0ef5ca381d810b7659f760f772    f57f69f947d28b037f0a477a9439df
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/me/.npm/_logs/    2024-07-27T19_23_20_514Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install has failed.

Why is there a problem when I am only using standard tools and have written no code at all ?
Is it the way I answered the initial questions which can cause issues ?
For information, I have this version of npx.
 % npx --version             

10.2.4

The issue does not come from NextJS or any package. It's your machine.
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied
That error line indicates that npm does not have permission to modify some specific directory. Based on rename '/Users/me/.npm/_cacache/tmp/77a0df01' - seems like a cache issue. There are multiple things you can try to do to solve it.
Clearing cache: npm cache clean --force
Or running as an administrator sudo npx create-next-app@latest
Should also check the directory permissions and if not sufficient (write permission) - grant it. Depending on ur OS - the terminal command might be different. Example sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm.

I see. I am using a  Mac (Sonoma 14.5). I solved part of the problem running npm cache clean --force as you suggest. But I still have the warnings about deprecated modules.

ignore them mostly. most of those warnings are that there is a newer version of that package while the current version of nextjs (latest) was built before the package update aka the older version. the package dependencies will most likely be updated with a newer version of the nextjs.
